# Convert a real string that looks like an array into a proper array

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have a string of `$data_regions` which when I

```
echo $data_regions
```

returns

```
["1","7"]
```

So its not a proper array its just a string mimicking an array. I need to convert this into a PROPER array of items so that I need to use a command of

```
echo print_r($data_regions)
```

which will return

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 7 )
```

I have tried spr_split but that is no good as it breaks it down into each individual character.

I suspect I need a preg_replace.. run through the entire string and grab everything in a " and add it to a new array.

Comment: I suppose you have `json`

Comment: This very much looks like JSON, so `json_decode` it. Unless you may expect other values there which are *not* JSON, in which case it's up to you to determine what format is being used here.

Comment: Also note that your JSON is an array of *strings*, so if you want to convert them into an array of integers, you'll also need to `intval()` them. This might not be necessary though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have in your string is json. PHP has a function `json_decode` which will directly change that string into an array:

```
$array = json_decode($data_regions);
```

Comment: That will return a `StdClass`. To return an `array`, you need to pass `true` as a second parameter.

Comment: @ishegg `print_r(json_decode('["1","7"]'));` displays `Array
(
    [0] => 1[1] => 7)`

Comment: @ishegg JSON arrays decode to PHP arrays either way.

Comment: Right, because this specific string is an encoded `array`. I just thought you should mention it.

Comment: I am feeling a bit stupid right now... no idea why my brain struggled with this.. of course its JSON, and for some reason I didnt see it even though I work with JSON all the time... going to hide now